# is it any formula to combine any array in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an array CF1:CF69. I need to combine the values of CF1:CF69. To combine these separately, I have built a formula

```
=CF1&"  "&CF2
```

But the problem is that I have to write all values manually from CF1 to CF69. Is it possible to deal with the entire array using any single formula?

Comment: Try with `=textjoin(" ",1,CF1:CF69)`

Comment: Or, `=JOIN(" ",CF1:CF69)`